# Issue with setting the parameters to camera

Tags: android, camera

I'm have an android app which works with the camera. So after a few atempts I started building my own camera by creating a class that implements `SurfaceHolder.Callback`. The big problem in all this is that in my method `surfaceChanged()` when I'm trying to set the parameters to the camera I get: FORCE CLOSE.

Here is how my method looks like:

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        Log.e(TAG, "surfaceChanged");
        if (mPreviewRunning) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        }

        Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
        List<Size> sizes = p.getSupportedPictureSizes();

        System.out.println("Lista de parametrii este urmatoarea:"+sizes);
        Size   size = sizes.get(0);
        p.setPictureSize(size.width, size.height);

        p.setPreviewSize(w, h);
        mCamera.setParameters(p);
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mCamera.startPreview();
        mPreviewRunning = true;
    }
```

If I try the above way:

```
Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
        List<Size> sizes = p.getSupportedPictureSizes();
        Size   size = sizes.get(0);
        p.setPictureSize(size.width, size.height);
```

Then `size` is `null` and I get error at this line:

```
Size size = sizes.get(0);
```

If I do this way:

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
            Log.e(TAG, "surfaceChanged");
            if (mPreviewRunning) {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
            }

            Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
            p.setPreviewSize(w, h);
            mCamera.setParameters(p);
            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mCamera.startPreview();
            mPreviewRunning = true;
        }
```

I get the following error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed
at android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Native Method)
at android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:914)
at com.SplashScreen.EditPhoto.surfaceChanged(EditPhoto.java:535)
at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:554)
at android.view.SurfaceView.dispatchDraw(SurfaceView.java:353)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1719)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1448)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1719)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1448)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6971)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:361)
```

So what's the proper way to set parameters?Thank you!

**EDIT**: This is how I instantiate my camera:

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.e(TAG, "surfaceCreated");
    mCamera = Camera.open();

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing it the proper way, I have a similar method, exactly like yours, that works perfectly. The only reason I could imagine for your method to fail are the width and height values. Check them out.  Check also if the mCamera object is properly instantiated.

I see that you call getSupportedPictureSize(), have you tried getSupportedPreviewSizes() ?

Cheers

Comment: On the emulator works great for me too.On the physical device which is a Sony Ericsson it crashes at setting the parameters,  when I'm doing something like:Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
            p.setPreviewSize(w, h);
            mCamera.setParameters(p);

Comment: Have no clue whatsoever.If I remove that line from my code then it works..but the picture is small:P

Comment: my point is, if you wish to increase the size of the preview you should set the values to something... try something like this
p.setPreviewSize(640, 480);

Comment: Yes, the preview gets bigger.But the picture size I can't get it bigger.If I input bigger values than this: p.setPictureSize(213,350), my emulator crashes!!!!And the device doesn't stand this line:p.setParameteres()

Comment: I've also added to my question the way I instantiate my camera!

Comment: set the same size as the preview. and by the way, you can't set picture sizes like (213, 350) they are not supported... I thought you were calling getSupportedPictureSizs()

Comment: I'm but on the emulator this method returns nulll.And on the physical device returns this:07-26 17:26:56.153: INFO/System.out(5428): Lista de parametrii este urmatoarea:[android.hardware.Camera$Size@65d4c50, android.hardware.Camera$Size@65d49ec, android.hardware.Camera$Size@50ddab8, android.hardware.Camera$Size@3fe4e00, android.hardware.Camera$Size@32ea628, android.hardware.Camera$Size@3be67b8, android.hardware.Camera$Size@27ef0c0, android.hardware.Camera$Size@27eefd0, android.hardware.Camera$Size@13f7860, android.hardware.Camera$Size@ef9a20]

Comment: It is strange that method returning null, but nevertheless my suggestions are: 
1) set the width/height value to something (and the same values) in both setPreviewSize and setPictureSize... try (640, 480) or (480,320); 2) make note, that the camera sizes change with screen orientation 3) I wouldn't use the emulator to test cammera stuff related since you can't actually see anything

Comment: @MobileCushion let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1843/discussion-between-george-and-mobilecushion)

Comment: Whats the difference between getSupportedPictureSize() and getSupportedPreviewSizes() (purpose/example)?

Comment: The getSupportedPictureSize() gives the list of supported sizes for taken pictures, using camera.takePicture(). The getSupportedPreviewSizes() return the available sizes for the resolution of the video shown on the the screen when you show a video preview.