# Width and height passed in surfaceChanged() not supported by setParameters()?

Tags: android, surfaceview, preview

I am having a RuntimeException error when calling Camera.setParameters() from the method surfaceChanged(). I saw other posts about the same issue, but didn't find a definite solution:
[Issue with setting the parameters to camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830723/problem-with-setting-the-parameters-to-camera)

My questions are:

1. Why should surfaceChanged() be called right after surfaceCreated()? It is counter intuitive  (at least to me) to start the preview in surfaceCreated(), only to stop it and restart another one in surfaceChanged().
2. When surfaceChanged() is called for the first time, what decides the width and height that are passed in? As suggested in the aforementioned post, and verified in my experiment, the values are not necessarily supported by Camera.setParameters(). See below for my code snippet and log information.
3. Before surfaceChanged() is called, is there a way to guarantee that the width and height values will be supported by Camera.setParameters()? It is possible to add code within surfaceChanged() to ensure that. For example, w and h can be compared against all supported preview sizes, and be changed to the closest supported values. However, doing so will hinder performance.

List below are my code snippet and the LogCat output. The logging info indicates that Camera.setParameters() within surfaceChanged() is causing the error. If I comment out the line where setParameters() is called, I don't see the error message any more.

[**Edit**: I am testing on an Amazon Kindle Fire HD. The Android version is 4.0.3, API 15]

Code snippet:

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // Log & debug
    Log.d(TAG, "surfaceCreated() is called");

    // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceCreated(): " + e.getMessage());
    }

    if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceCreated(): preview surface does not exist yet!");
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // Log & debug
    Log.d(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed() is called");

    // Stop preview and release camera 
    if (holder.getSurface() != null) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        //mCamera.release();  //should we release camera here?
        //mCamera = null;
    }
    else {
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed(): preview surface does not exist");
    }
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    // Log and debug
    Log.d(TAG, "surfaceChanged() is called with width = " + w);
    Log.d(TAG, "surfaceChanged() is called with height = " + h);

    // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
    // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.
    if (holder.getSurface() == null) {
      Log.d(TAG, "surfaceChanged(): preview surface does not exist");
      return;
    }

    // stop preview before making changes
    try {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceChanged(): tried to stop a non-existent preview " + e.getMessage());
    }

    // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
    // reformatting changes here
    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
    List<Size> mSizes = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();

    // list all 25 supported preview sizes
    // i==25 will cause an "IndexOutofBoundsException"
    for (int i=0; i<25; i++) {
        Size mSize  = mSizes.get(i);
        if (mSize == null) break;
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceChanged() i = " + i);
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceChanged() preview width = " + mSize.width);
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceChanged() preview height = " + mSize.height);
    }
    Size       mSize  = mSizes.get(0);
    if(mSize != null) { //make sure we don't pull a NullException.
        if (w > mSize.width) w  = mSize.width;
        if (h > mSize.height) h = mSize.height;
        params.setPreviewSize(w, h); //set the size, since we know it. 
    } 
    mCamera.setParameters(params); //set the parameters now. 

    // start preview with new settings
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceChanged() restart preview " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

LogCat output:

```
02-13 10:46:08.113: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceCreated() is called
02-13 10:46:08.496: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() is called with width = 1072
02-13 10:46:08.496: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() is called with height = 705
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() i = 0
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview width = 1280
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview height = 720
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() i = 1
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview width = 960
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview height = 720
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() i = 2
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview width = 800
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview height = 480
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() i = 3
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview width = 720
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview height = 576
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() i = 4
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview width = 720
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview height = 480
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() i = 5
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview width = 768
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview height = 576
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() i = 6
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview width = 640
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview height = 480
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() i = 7
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview width = 320
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview height = 240
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() i = 8
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview width = 352
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview height = 288
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() i = 9
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview width = 240
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview height = 160
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() i = 10
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview width = 176
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview height = 144
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() i = 11
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview width = 160
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview height = 120
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() i = 12
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview width = 128
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview height = 96
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() i = 13
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview width = 720
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview height = 1280
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() i = 14
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview width = 480
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview height = 800
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() i = 15
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview width = 576
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview height = 720
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() i = 16
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview width = 576
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview height = 768
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() i = 17
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview width = 480
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview height = 720
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() i = 18
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview width = 480
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview height = 640
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() i = 19
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview width = 288
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview height = 352
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() i = 20
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview width = 240
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview height = 320
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() i = 21
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview width = 240
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview height = 160
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() i = 22
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview width = 144
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview height = 176
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() i = 23
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview width = 120
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview height = 160
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() i = 24
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview width = 96
02-13 10:46:08.941: D/CameraPreview(2886): surfaceChanged() preview height = 128
02-13 10:46:08.957: D/AndroidRuntime(2886): Shutting down VM
02-13 10:46:08.957: W/dalvikvm(2886): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a6c1f8)
02-13 10:46:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(2886): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-13 10:46:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(2886): java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed
02-13 10:46:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(2886):     at android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Native Method)
02-13 10:46:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(2886):     at android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:1295)
02-13 10:46:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(2886):     at com.xyz.camera.CameraPreview.surfaceChanged(CameraPreview.java:109)
02-13 10:46:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(2886):     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:544)
02-13 10:46:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(2886):     at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:81)
02-13 10:46:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(2886):     at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:169)
02-13 10:46:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(2886):     at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:590)
02-13 10:46:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(2886):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1630)
02-13 10:46:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(2886):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2462)
02-13 10:46:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(2886):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-13 10:46:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(2886):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-13 10:46:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(2886):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4486)
02-13 10:46:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(2886):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-13 10:46:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(2886):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-13 10:46:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(2886):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-13 10:46:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(2886):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-13 10:46:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(2886):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: which api are you compiling against and which device are you testing on?

Comment: @Raigex: good question. Amazon Kindle Fire HD (android 4.0.3, API 15).

Comment: Anyone knows the answer question 1  ?

Comment: Also surface called anytime the surface size is changed. So when the surface is created its size is automatically changed. Then it is called each time you change the orientation (portrait to landscape or reverse).

Answer (score 0):

Well one of the problems that you might be getting this for is the fact that since you are using api 15 then you should use getSupportedVideoSizes() as that is from api 11. I had a similar problem with setting parameters on certain devices (those running honeycomb and above) because the preview size and the supported video size are not always the same.

EDIT:: in regards to your comment:
I would output all supportedpreviewsizes for your test device. which you already have. Then I would take one (eg: the second that you get) and statically set it for testing purposes

eg:

```
for int (i = 0; i < mSizes.size(); i ++)
    {
        Log each size;
    }
```

take a random size from it :eg 480 x 800 and set it

```
    params.setPreviewSize(480, 800);
```

This will tell you for sure if setting the the preview size makes shows proper sizes.

EDIT2:
 I will update my answer again to clarify my comment

inside onSurfaceChanged
have two variables

```
int width = 0;
int height = 0;
```

then in your if statement

```
if (w > mSize.width) width = mSize.width;
if (h > mSize.height) height = mSize.height;
```

Also what you are doing is getting the equivalent of

mSizes.get(mSize.size() -1). since you w and h are always gonna be larger than mSize.width and mSize.height

EDIT 3:
OK based on your comments. 
you want to initialize the camera inside the onSufaceCreated()
and change setPreviewSize(w,h) to setPreviewSize(mSizes.get(mSizes.size() -1).width, mSizes.get(mSizes.size() -1).height);

then add a function that sets the surfaceView to whatever size you want ()

```
surfaceParams = surfaceView.getLayoutParameters();
surfaceParams.setWidth(somewidthyouwant);
surfaceParams.setHeight(someHeightYouWant);
surfaceView.setLayoutParams(surfaceParams);
```

this will set you surfaceview to whatever size you want it.

Comment: Unfortunately, getSupportedVideoSizes() returns a null. It seems to be  a confirmed Android bug. Although the bug is reported on the emulator, I get a null pointer on the Kindle device too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932199/android-getsupportedvideosizes-returns-null-on-emulator

Comment: I verified with the following code snippet. setPreviewSize(800, 480) works fine, but setPreviewSize(w, h) crashes with the same error as shown in my OP.
      Size       mSize  = mSizes.get(0);
     if(mSize != null) { //make sure we don't pull a NullException.
      params.setPreviewSize(800, 480); //set the size, since we know it. 
      //params.setPreviewSize(w, h); //set the size, since we know it. 
     } 
     mCamera.setParameters(params); //set the parameters now.

Comment: Ok final thing i can think of is that before you setPreview size check if you actually changed w and h which are two variables you obtain from the callback (i dont know if you can modify them) I think that might be the problem.

Comment: Yes I can modify them within surfaceChanged() and I must modify them to match a pair of supported preview sizes. If I don't modify them, setParameters() crashes. That's why I am asking this question.

Comment: @hubeir So you are not trying to modify the preview size. You are trying to modify the surface view that you are using the show the preview??

Comment: I don't really know the difference between a preview and a surface view, but I assume setPreviewSize(800, 480) modies the preview size?

Comment: No. The preview size is something like what dimens it sends to the surface view (which is the view that projects the camera) the surfaceView size takes those pixels and stretches them to whatever the surface view size is (eg full screen, 2px by 2px). I would suggest setting the preview size to the max one and then modify the surface view like I will show you in my above post.

Comment: In your edit 3, are you suggesting that I initialize the surface view size in onSufaceCreated()? I'll need to do some reading to understand more. Thanks for the helps!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. But yes you should initialize the surface view size after you start the camera.